# swift distance between cells in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview.
I have two questions.

1. I want to have tableview with a gap between cells that in this distance background can be seen.
2. In each cell, two corners from the four corners rounded.

As shown below

[image]

Comment: The easiest solution? Use a background that already has rounded corners.

Comment: This looks more like a UICollectionViewController, you should try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can search it in google but for set corner :

```
var customerLayer = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft , .BottomRight], cornerRadii: 10)
self.layer.addSublayer(customerLayer)
```